# grep strings from a text file and copy them to a directory in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

In CMake 2.8.12, how to grep strings (each string represent a file name) from a text file and copy them to a directory?

For example, I have a text file xx/yy/a.txt that contains:

```
xx xx xx abc="some_file_name1.txt" xx xx xx
xx xx xx abc="some_file_name2.txt" xx xx xx
xx xx xx abc="some_file_name3.txt" xx xx xx
```

where 'xx' could be some random strings.

I need to extract `some_file_name1.txt, some_file_name2.txt and some_file_name3.txt` first, form a correct path for each of them by appending the path prefix `xx/yy/` to each extracted string, then copy each file to directory `mydir/`

I know how to do this in bash script but have no clue on how to do this in CMake, in particular, I need to do it inside ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND for a post build target.

Thanks!

Comment: "I need to do it inside ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND for a post build target" - Using `add_custom_command` implies that you need a command line which performs the task. The command line could involve bash script, CMake script (which is created separately from `CMakeLists.txt`) or just using combination of `grep`/`sed`/`awk` with proper parameters. So the first task is to create a command line or script which performs required task.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the reason that I want to do it in CMake way is to support multiple platforms. Obviously, bash script is not easily portable.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a CMake script that you invoke via a custom command. Something like this:

```
# ProcessFile.cmake:
file(READ "${ProcessFile_INPUT_PATH}" ProcessFile_CONTENT)

# Replace newlines with semicolon so that it is treated as a list by CMake
# Will need to escape existing semicolons beforehand if file contains any.
string(REPLACE "\n" ";" ProcessFile_LINES "${ProcessFile_CONTENT}")
foreach(_line ${ProcessFile_LINES})
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^.+abc=\"(.+)\".+$" "xx/yy/\\1" _file_path "${_line}")
  file(COPY "${_file_path}" DESTINATION "${ProcessFile_OUTPUT_DIR}")
endforeach()

# CMakeLists.txt:
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "output-file"
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_ROOT}" -DProcessFile_INPUT_PATH="xx/yy/a.txt" -DProcessFile_OUTPUT_DIR="mydir" -P ProcessFile.cmake)
```

I did not test the scripts, but this is the gist:

- `ProcessFile.cmake` parses the file, iterate on each line, extracts the file name and copy the file.
- The `add_custom_command()` in `CMakeLists.txt` invokes the `ProcessFile.cmake` script, giving it the location of the input file and the output directory.